# Passing props/params to stripe elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, stripe-payments

I am using React Router to grab the `:profile_product_id`, however, I cannot access it from the stripe submit. In normal Django or Rails, I can simply create a nested form and submit it that way. In this case, it's all in React with an API backend and I cannot for the life of me keep the id in the form submit.

On the products page, I use a `Link` to navigate to the checkout page:

map through products...

```
<Link to={{pathname: `/profiles/${this.state.slug}/Order/${product.id}`, state: {profile_product_id: product.id}}}>Buy</Link>
```

...

I am then brought to the form where I want to grab the email along with a credit card. In order to open the CC form, they need to enter email and submit email first then press a Continue button that renders the CC form.

So there is an `Order.js` and a `Checkout.js`:

**Order.js**

```
class OrderInstagram extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: true,
        profile_product_id: '',
        email: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  _showStripe = (bool) => {
    this.setState({
      showStripe: bool
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/products/${profile_product_id}`, {
    })
      .then(res => {
          this.setState({ profile_product: res.data.results[0] });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      })
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {state} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Email:
            <input name="email" type="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
        </form>
        <div>
          Click the buttons to toggle the message <br/>
          <div onClick={this._showStripe.bind(null, true)}>show</div>
          <div onClick={this._showStripe.bind(null, false)}>hide</div>
          { this.state.showStripe &&
            (<div>
              {this.state.profile_product.price}
              <CheckoutForm />
            </div>) }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default withRouter(OrderInstagram);
```

Clicking `this.state.showStripe` will append the CC form...

**CheckoutForm.js:**

```
class CheckoutForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const {stripe, elements} = this.props;

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: cardElement,
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log('[error]', error);
    } else {
      console.log('[PaymentMethod]', paymentMethod);
      // sends AJAX POST to server to send to Stripe (removed for brevity)
    }
  };

  render() {
    const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_9');

    const {stripe} = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="stripe-form">
        <CardElement
              //brevity
        />
        <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
          Pay
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const InjectedCheckoutForm = () => {
  return (
    <ElementsConsumer>
      {({elements, stripe}) => (
        <CheckoutForm elements={elements} stripe={stripe} />
      )}
    </ElementsConsumer>
  );
};

const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_9');

const StripeForm = (e) => {
  const [profile_product_id, setprofile_product_id] = useState(e.location.state.profile_product_id);

  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <InjectedCheckoutForm />
    </Elements>
  );
};

// export default withRouter(CheckoutForm);
export default withRouter(StripeForm);
```

Now, as you see I did `const StripeForm = (e) => {` and this initially receives the `state: {profile_product_id: product.id}` I sent but once I submit the form, all the states are unable to be retrieved.

As you also see, the `export default withRouter()` is what makes it available. If I only use `export default withRouter(CheckoutForm);` then the stripe form will not load with:

`Error: Could not find Elements context; You need to wrap the part of your app that mounts <CardElement> in an <Elements> provider` `Uncaught Error: Could not find Elements context; You need to wrap the part of your app that mounts <CardElement> in an <Elements> provider.`

I have also tried putting all of this into one file but the same issue happens.

How can I access the parameters from the `Route` within the stripe form?

The goal is for the params to be sent along with the stripe submit.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If possible could you elaborate as to what the issue is exactly? The error message you shared from Stripe doesn't seem to be the error that you're running into initially, but an error that you ran into in trying to solve your first problem, is that right? If so, what is your first problem? You say that you "cannot access `profile_product_id` from the stripe submit" - what does that mean exactly? Which component/method are you trying to access this variable from, what's the expected value, and what's the actual value you're seeing?

Comment: @ttmarek the error is only when I use export default withRouter(CheckoutForm); then the stripe form will not load with.  I am only able to get the params in one and not the other